# keyboard.is_pressed() recognizes combination of two keys wrongly in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

This **example** code:

```
while 1:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl+alt'):
        print('to')
```

But when I press `alt+ctrl` it prints `to`. Tried using:

```
while 1:

    if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl+alt') and not keyboard.is_pressed('alt+ctrl') :
        print('to')
```

But doesn't work.
**I want it to print `to` only when I press `ctrl+alt` and not `alt+ctrl` or any other key**.How to do this. I would guess editing source code (not too familiar with this but if it works it's ok)
Or more specifically I want it to recognize it only when I hold down `ctrl` then press `alt` while still holding down `ctrl`.

```
Operating System: windows 7
Python Version: 3.8.8
Keyboard: Logitech k200
IDE: pycharm community edition
Module: keyboard module latest version
Module Link: https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard
Pip Version: Latest
```

Edit Fixed:

```
import keyboard

def on_alt(event):
    if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl'):
        print('Ctrl + Alt pressed')

keyboard.on_press_key('alt', on_alt)
time.sleep(1e6)
```

Comment: Partially yes because I **do not** want module to recognize it after I release ctrl. Or more specifically I want it to recognize it when I **hold down ctrl** then **press alt while holding down ctrl**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed. The following code workes in the latest version

```
import keyboard

def on_alt(event):
    if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl'):
        print('Ctrl + Alt pressed')

keyboard.on_press_key('alt', on_alt)
time.sleep(1e6)
```

Answer (score 0):

while not just make it two if statements

```
if keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl") then
    if keyboard.is_pressed("alt") then
        print("done")
    end
end
```

(Not written in python)

Comment: Nah it doesn't work I don't know why